# Filtering data out of a long string

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, string, substring

I'm scanning data from a QR-code (VCARDS) that I receive in multiple ways. These are the different options of receiving the data:

**OPTION 1:**

```
BEGIN:VCARD
VERSION:2.1
N:Lastname;Firstname
FN:Firstname Lastname
ORG:Lol Group
TITLE:Project Engineer
TEL;WORK:+32 (0)11 12 13 14
ADR;WORK:Industrielaan 1;2250 Olen;Belgium
EMAIL:link.com
URL:http://www.link.com
END:VCARD
```

**OPTION 2:**

```
BEGIN:VCARDFN:Barend VercauterenTEL:+32(0)9 329 93 06EMAIL:Barend.Vercauterenëesc.beURL:http://www.esc.beN:Vercauteren;BarendADR:Grote Steenweg 39;9840;De PinteORG:ESC bvbaROLE:sales consultantVERSION:3.0END:VCARD
```

**OPTION 3:**

```
BEGIN:VCARDVERSION:2.1N:Deblieck;Tommy;;DhrFN:Tommy DeblieckTITLE:ZaakvoerderORG:QBMT bvbaADR:;;Kleine Pathoekweg 44;Brugge;West-Vlaanderen;8000;Belgi≠A0171TEL;WORK;PREF:+32 479302972TEL;CELL:+32 479302972EMAIL:tdëqbmt.beURL:www.qbis.beEND:VCARD
```

As you can see it can happen that all the text is attached to each other .. .

I need some data to automatically fill in the form (I'm doing this in jQuery). I need the firstname, lastname, organisation and telephone number.

So I need the data after N, ORG and TEL. I've already have a way to receive the data with option 1. But not when the text is all attached to each other.

My code for receiving the correct data with option 1:

```
var fname = /FN:(.*)/g;
var org = /ORG:(.*)/g;
var tel = /TEL;[^:]*:(.*)/g;

var fullname, firstname, morg, mtel;

fullname = fname.exec(qr_data);
fullname = fullname[1];
var array = fullname.split(' ');
firstname = array[0];
array.shift();

var lastname = '';

if(array.length > 1){
    $.each(array, function(index, item) {
        lastname += item ;
    });
}
else
{
    lastname = array[0];
}

morg = org.exec(qr_data);
mtel = tel.exec(qr_data);

if(firstname)
{
    $("#firstname").val(firstname);
}

if(lastname)
{
    $("#name").val(lastname);
}

if(morg)
{
    $("#company").val(morg[1]);
}

if(mtel)
{
    $("#number").val(mtel[1]);
}
```

But how can I get these data with the other 2 options?

Comment: It is not a good idea to reask the same question. You can [update the previous one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31802227/filter-data-out-of-long-string-vcard) with your new findings.

Comment: I've updated my topic ..